# iteration over hashmap list

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to iterate over the HashMap list and retrieve the key and the values (value 1 and value2). There is  a error at this line that says
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry>"

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : Map.entrySet())
```

Am I doing anything wrong. Please help me out. Here is the entire code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Map<String, List<String>> conceptMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    Map<String, List<String>> PropertyMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/"));
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            String [] column = nextLine.split(":");
            if (column[0].equals ("Property")){
                if (column.length == 4) {
                    PropertyMap.put(column [1], Arrays.asList(column[2], column[3]));    
                }
                else {
                    conceptMap.put (column [1], Arrays.asList (column[2], column[3]));
                }
            }
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : Map.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                List<String> valueList = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println("Key: " + key);
                System.out.print("Values: ");
                for (String s : valueList) {
                    System.out.print(s + " ");
                }
            }
        }

        scanner.close();
    }    
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Any particular language?

Answer (score 2):

Change `Map.entrySet()` to `PropertyMap.entrySet()` or `conceptMap.entrySet()`

Answer (score 1):

The `Map.entrySet()` method declared by the Map interface returns a collection-view of the map (returns a `Set`). Each of these set elements is a `Map.Entry` object. The *only* way to obtain a reference to a map entry is from the iterator of this collection-view.

If you want to return a `Set` you inserted into the map, you have to call it on the Collection you placed it in:

`PropertyMap.entrySet()` and `conceptMap.entrySet()` will return Sets.

`Map.entrySet()` is not calling the method on either of your instantiated `Maps`.

Answer (score 0):

Map.entrySet() returns a collection view of the map.change it in to conceptMap.entrySet() or
propertyMap.entrySet